# Jenkins Job stuck at disk usage

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I have a couple of Jenkins Job running on different slaves that are stuck at the end of the build at the below step:

> Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cancelled the job from the Jenkins Home page where we can see the jobs running under different slaves and the job completed as SUCCESS